# Calling Java Rest API from javascript as JSONP returns invalid label error

Tags: java, api, rest, jsonp

i have created a java webservice to return country list

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getcountrylist", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody
@ApiIgnore
Object getcountrylist(@RequestParam String pvtToken,
        @RequestParam String lan) {

    System.out.println(API_TAG + "Request recevied to get CountryList");
    System.out.println("DB:"+dbName);
    if (!this.pvtToken.equals(pvtToken)) {
        CountryList countryList = new CountryList();            
        return new ResponseEntity<CountryList>(countryList,
                HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
    CountryList countryList = avlMobileAPIService.getCountryList(lan);      
    return new ResponseEntity<CountryList>(countryList, HttpStatus.OK);     

}
```

i need to call the above webservice from javascript as JSONP, i wrote the following javascript code as below

```
function buttonClick(){

$.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "jsonp",         
           crossDomain: true,
           url: "http://localhost:8080/api/getcountrylist",
             data: {pvtToken:"JXku56AE0067YtRUSAZEE",lan:"en"},
             Accept: "application/jsonp",
             jsonpCallback:  function(data, status){
                alert('callback');
                alert(data);
           },              
           success: function(data, status){
                alert('sucess');
           },


           });

}
```

Above function call the webservice and returns the list, but shows "**invalid label error**" on client side.

```
{"countrylist":[{"countryId":"4","countryCodeAlpha2":"AF","countryCodeAlpha3":"AFG","countryName":"Afghanistan ","isdCode":"93"},{"countryId":"5","countryCodeAlpha2":"AL","countryCodeAlpha3":"ALB","countryName":"Albania ","isdCode":"355"},{"countryId":"6","countryCodeAlpha2":"DZ","countryCodeAlpha3":"DZA","countryName":"Algeria ","isdCode":"213"},{"countryId":"7","countryCodeAlpha2":"AS","countryCodeAlpha3":"ASM","countryName":"American Samoa ","isdCode":"684"}]}
```

i found in some article it says, the that ajax call expects JSONP , but return JSON data.

What is the solution?

Comment: i also tried with the following attribute on ajax call - Accept: "application/json", contentType: "application/json", but same result.

Comment: Does the REST API actually support JSONP? (e.g: returns JSON response with trailing javascript code which executes on the client). If not, then you'll likely just want to use the `success` callback in the `.ajax` method. From your example, it looks like plain `JSON`, not `JSONP`.

Comment: i dont know, what should i do in java side to support JSONP. i tried with many examples.

Comment: You don't need to. Just use the existing `JSON` response with the `success` callback in `.ajax`. Change `dataType` to `json` and the result will be parsed for you, returning an object as the first parameter to the `success` callback.

Comment: I tried with the below code $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "json", 
           url: "http://localhost:8080/api/mobile_getcountrylist",
             data: {pvtToken:"JXku56AE0067YtRUSAZEE",lan:"en"},
           contentType: "application/json", 
           success: function(data, status){
             alert('sucess');
           },
                
           });     return error "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:8080/api/mobile_getcountrylist?pvtToken=JXku56AE0067YtRUSAZEE&lan=en"

Comment: Please not : rest api is different application and can be hosted any where,  and i am trying to call the api from other client application. so we should use JSONP instead of JSON

Comment: Error `500` indicates an error on the server-side (not the JavaScript code). Can you check the logs there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

reffer this link
http://www.iceycake.com/2012/06/xml-json-jsonp-web-service-endpoints-spring-3-1/

or try in this simple way

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mobile_getcountrylist", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/x-javascript"})
    @ResponseBody   
    public Object mobile_getcountrylist( @RequestParam("callback") String jsonpCallback) {

        System.out.println(API_TAG + "Request recevied to get CountryList");    
        CountryList countryList = avlMobileAPIService.getCountryList("en");
        //countryList.setJsonCallback(jsonpCallback); 
        return convertToJsonP(countryList,jsonpCallback);
    }

    private String convertToJsonP(Object o,String jsonpCallback){
        String outputmessage=null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            outputmessage=mapper.writeValueAsString(o);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(outputmessage!=null){
            outputmessage=jsonpCallback + "(" + outputmessage + ")";
        }
        return outputmessage;   
    }
```

Javascript code

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/mobile_getcountrylist',
        crossDomain: true,
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType:'application/json',
        success: function(data) {        
         alert('ok');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I know this post is old but it helped me a lot !! +1